# getDefaultApplication is not a function

Tags: air

I'm developing and AIR application in html.  I have:

```
var myDir = air.File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("HelloWorld");
myDir.openWithDefaultApplication(); // This works.
var X = myDir.getDefaultApplication(); // This doesn't.
```

It instead says "getDefaultApplication is not a function."
But it's talked about on page 337 of AIR 1.5 Applications with HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the official [flash.filesystem.File documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) (which hasn't changed since AIR 1.0), there is no *getDefaultApplication(*) method.

i believe you are looking for getDefaultApplication() method that is available in the [flash.desktop.NativeApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html) class.